# Boost XML - get next node

Tags: c++, xml, boost

The following code attempts to get data from an xml file and add it to a custom SensorConfiguration class, and then add that to a map of these SensorConfigurations

My problem is that it always takes the first sensor configuration in the second foreach loop.
I know why, but I don't know the correct syntax, and I'm not sure how to google this.

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<sensorconfigurations>
    <configuration>
        <name>SensorConfiguration1</name>
        <sensorid>1</sensorid>
        <signalindex>1</signalindex>
        <mappingscheme>mappingscheme1</mappingscheme>
        <soundpack>test1.wav</soundpack>
    </configuration>
    <configuration>
        <name>SensorConfiguration2</name>
        <sensorid>2</sensorid>
        <signalindex>2</signalindex>
        <mappingscheme>mappingscheme1</mappingscheme>
        <soundpack>test2.wav</soundpack>
    </configuration>
    <configuration>
        <name>SensorConfiguration3</name>
        <sensorid>3</sensorid>
        <signalindex>3</signalindex>
        <mappingscheme>mappingscheme2</mappingscheme>
        <soundpack>test3.wav</soundpack>
    </configuration>
</sensorconfigurations>
</root>
```

Here's the entire function constructor-method:

```
SensorConfigurationBank::SensorConfigurationBank()
{   
string m_level;
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
ptree pt;
read_xml("SensorConfigurationBank.xml", pt);
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v,
    pt.get_child("root.sensorconfigurations"))
{
    SensorConfiguration newSensorConf;
    BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &w,
        pt.get_child("root.sensorconfigurations.configuration"))
    {
        if(w.first == "name")
        {
            newSensorConf.setName(w.second.data());
        }
        if(w.first == "sensorid")
        {
            string stringToInt = w.second.data();
            istringstream iss(stringToInt);
            int value;
            iss >> value;
            newSensorConf.setSensorID(value);
        }
        if(w.first == "signalindex")
        {
            string stringToInt = w.second.data();
            istringstream iss(stringToInt);
            int value;
            iss >> value;
            newSensorConf.setSignalIndex(value);
        }
        if(w.first == "mappingscheme")
        {
            newSensorConf.setMappingScheme(getMappingScheme(w.second.data()));
        }
        if(w.first == "soundpack")
        {
            newSensorConf.setSoundPack(w.second.data());
        }
    }
    sensorConfigurations_.insert(make_pair(newSensorConf.getName(), newSensorConf));
}
//save();
}
```

I know it's slightly incomprehensible, but here's the important part:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &w,
        pt.get_child("root.sensorconfigurations.configuration"))
```

Instead of getting the specific child 'configuration', I want it to get to the child that the first loop is looking at, so it looks at configuration #2 instead of getting configuration #1 up to an infinite number of times.

It's basically just the last line of code I pasted above that needs to be changed somehow, then I think it will work! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `get_child` gets a single tree with the specified node name. You seem to expect it to return all matching nodes. This is simply not the case.
- Foreach iterates the value, you didn't use `v` at all. Change:

  ```
      if (v.first == "configuration")
      {
           // use v.second, which is the subtree
  ```
- node paths are relative, so don't start with "root.sensorconfigurations" all the time:

  ```
  BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type & v, pt.get_child("root.sensorconfigurations")) {

      if (v.first == "configuration")
      {
          SensorConfiguration newSensorConf;

          BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type & w, v.second) {
              if (w.first == "name") {
                  newSensorConf.setName(w.second.data());
              }
  ```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9c131a9b7002359)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/strong_typedef.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

struct SensorConfiguration {
    void setName(std::string const& v) { _name = v; }
    std::string getName() const { return _name; }
    void setMappingScheme(std::string) {}
    void setSoundPack(std::string) {}
    void setSensorID(int) {}
    void setSignalIndex(int) {}

    std::string _name;
};

struct MyDemo {

    MyDemo() {
        std::string m_level;
        using boost::property_tree::ptree;
        ptree pt;
        read_xml("SensorConfigurationBank.xml", pt);
        BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type & v, pt.get_child("root.sensorconfigurations")) {

            if (v.first == "configuration")
            {
                SensorConfiguration newSensorConf;

                BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type & w, v.second) {
                    if (w.first == "name") {
                        newSensorConf.setName(w.second.data());
                    }
                    if (w.first == "sensorid") {
                        std::string stringToInt = w.second.data();
                        std::istringstream iss(stringToInt);
                        int value;
                        iss >> value;
                        newSensorConf.setSensorID(value);
                    }
                    if (w.first == "signalindex") {
                        std::string stringToInt = w.second.data();
                        std::istringstream iss(stringToInt);
                        int value;
                        iss >> value;
                        newSensorConf.setSignalIndex(value);
                    }
                    if (w.first == "mappingscheme") {
                        newSensorConf.setMappingScheme(getMappingScheme(w.second.data()));
                    }
                    if (w.first == "soundpack") {
                        newSensorConf.setSoundPack(w.second.data());
                    }
                }
                sensorConfigurations_.insert(make_pair(newSensorConf.getName(), newSensorConf));
            }
        }
        // save();

    }

    std::map<std::string, SensorConfiguration> sensorConfigurations_;

    template <typename T>
        std::string getMappingScheme(T const& v) {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
            return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(v);
        }

};

int main() { 
    MyDemo demo;

    for(auto & e : demo.sensorConfigurations_)
        std::cout << e.first << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Ah, all I needed was the syntax 'v.second' instead of the pt.get_child thing. Thank you!